# How do I have Broccoli compiler comment which file CSS came from?

Tags: css, ember-cli, broccolijs

I'm new to [broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli), but I have experience with Ruby on Rails' asset pipeline. I'm currently working on an Ember CLI app.

In broccoli, in development mode, I would love it if the compiler would write out the name of the file where the CSS came from as a comment preceding the code itself.

I know I can do this manually by adding comments myself to each file, but I'm hoping there is a configuration directive that I can put in my `Brocfile.js`.

Short of adding in comments to each file manually, is there an easy way to increase the verbosity of the compiled output in dev mode to include this?

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting an element reveals the name of the file it came from

[image: scss screenshot]

Clicking on the file name shows you the file and the line in the original scss/css file.

[image: original file]

Comment: Yeah, I didn't create the ember-cli app originally, and I'm new to it. Right now, all the css is getting compiled into a single file (kinda like in production mode) and I can see the unminified css, I'd like there to be a comment between each file that gets concatenated.

What you showed indicates that maybe changing a broccoli setting somewhere, I can get it to give me one file per source file, not one large, monolithic file. I'll check that out. Thanks, @kitler!